# Mongoose - find().where() query - Error: Can't use $size

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose exception when making this query

```
      if (args.filter?.authors) {
        if (args.filter?.match === AuthorMatch.EXACT_MATCH) {
          worksModel.where({
            "authors.id": {
              $size: args.filter.authors.length,
              $all: args.filter.authors,
            },
          });
        }
```

What I am looking for is that `authors.id` array is exactly the same as `args.filter.authors`.

Directly on Mongo works just fine, but with Mongoose I get: `Error: Can't use $size`

Any clue why this is happening and how could it be solved?

Comment: What does a sample document look like? is `authors.id` an array?

Comment: yes, `authors.id` is an array of `ObjectId`